# What Am I? - My First Riddle: With jolt or breath, I dine with death

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My first riddle:

> With jolt or breath; I dine with death
>
> Unwanted by most; light I can boast
>
> Lectern or wall; tethered, not all
>
> Your will or my squall, the point of my call

#### Hint 1:

> By use of metaphor, neither **squall** nor **call** make comment on decibel, though they be related.

#### Hint 2:

> Watch out for word play!

#### Hint 3:

> I'll admit: I bent the rules of punctuation a tiny bit. I've adjusted 3 little markings; hopefully, this will point you in the right direction and the answer will click right away!

Comment: I am assuming from the title it's a thing or maybe an occupation, but not a person, correct?

Comment: @Respect My Authoritah, You are correct

Comment: When you stated Electricity was incorrect, does that mean you also pan lightning?

Comment: @zfrisch, yes, that is correct

Comment: Did you bend the rules of spelling ("lecturn") intentionally?

Comment: @Michael Myers Hmm... the online thesaurus gave me the misspelled version. Yes, it is "lectern", and the misspelling is unintentional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a:

> Mouse

Hint 1 spoiler:

> The squall and call each refer to a noise. Both computer mice and animal mice make quiet sounds (squall can mean a high-pitched noise).

Hint 2 spoiler:

> The answer itself is a word play. Also, "light" and "point" are word plays.

Hint 3 spoiler:

> **point** you in the right direction and the answer will **click** right away

With jolt or breath

> The mouse can be electric or living

I dine with death

> Mice are often killed while eating at a trap

Unwanted by most

> Mice are most often considered pests

Light I can boast

> A reference to optical and laser computer mice. "Light" can also refer to weight.

Lectern or wall

> Computer mice on a desk or real mice in a wall

Tethered, not all

> Wired or wireless computer mice

Your will or my squall, the point of my call

> Your will = using a computer mouse to select an item
>  My squall = Etymology: "squeal" + "bawl". A squall can be a high-pitched noise. Hint 1 says it can be quiet, like a squeak.
>  The point of my call = Word play: "point" is a reference to a mouse pointer, but also means "purpose". The call is a noise, and the purpose of a mouse making noise is his own squeaking, and the purpose of a computer mouse making a noise (click) is the will of the person using it.

Comment: @Adam Denoon How does this answer make use of the mispelling of "lectern"?

Comment: The misspelling was unintentional

Comment: This is a great answer. If this isn't the right answer, it's probably better than the intended one!

Comment: Congratulations to Tyler W for solving the riddle!

Comment: Thanks to Adam for filling in the blanks...I probably only had about 50% of the clues figured out initially so I'm glad my guess was correct!

Comment: I thought of this days ago but I only thought computer mouse! nice job

Answer (score 4):

**Third attempt**

Could it be,

> A sound

With jolt or breath, I dine with death

> sound can be formed by jolt or someone talking, breath, and dies off quickly

Unwanted by most, light I can boast

> Most people don't want to listen to a lecture and I would bet even less want to hear someone boasting about light

Lecturn or wall, tethered, not all

> You lecture at a lecturn and sound echoes off walls but they are not connected

Your will or my squall, the point of my call

> Talking can be your will and squall and call make sounds

---

**Second attempt**

Could it be,

> A gun shot

With jolt or breath, I dine with death

> An accidental shot or someone yelling the order to fire, causing death

Unwanted by most, light I can boast

> I don't think most people want to be shot and a muzzle flare produces light

Lecturn or wall, tethered, not all

> There is a possibility of being shot anywhere, it doesn't matter if you are in class at a lecturn or in a back alley against a wall.

Your will or my squall, the point of my call

> shooting someone could be meditated, your will, or the sound of the gun going off, my squall.

---

**First attempt**

Could it be,

> Electricity

With jolt or breath, I dine with death

> Electricity can jolt you and bring you back to life or it could kill you if too much of a jolt

Unwanted by most, light I can boast

> Most people don't want to be shocked and electricity can produce light

Lecturn or wall, tethered, not all

> Electricity is not tethered to anything

Your will or my squall, the point of my call

> Lightning forms in storms, or squalls

Comment: Excellent thinking! I was almost convinced that could be a possible answer to my riddle, but it's not. Keep trying!

Comment: Perhaps a tesla coil, then?

Comment: @itriedacrab No, sir

Comment: My thoughts too, its the call part it doesnt fit

Comment: @Spacemonkey I interpreted that as the point of origin and the point of origin of lightning is the storm clouds, or squall. The will part is what I couldn't come up with a good answer for.

Comment: For the bullet guess, it says *my squall* so it can't be the shooter's anger. Maybe it's a firearm going off accidentally, making a *squall*.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah "Squall-a sudden violent gust of wind or a localized storm, especially one bringing rain, snow, or sleet." The hint says that it is used as a metaphor and that definition makes me think of anger

Comment: I get that, but it says *my* squall referring to the object in question, which according to your guess would be the *gun shot* not the person shooting.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah I get what you're saying. I think I'll just say the squall of the firearm. I don't think it needs to be accidental

Comment: You guys are excellent thinkers! You're missing the answer, but that kind of thinking will get you much closer. As Hint 1 infers, the definition of "squall" I have in mind refers to something audible (related to "call"), with no comment on decible (could be a very large sound, or a very small sound). I will provide another hint tomorrow :)

Comment: @SirParselot Your third attempt is incorrect... check out the new hint!

Comment: @SirParselot, thanks for being the hardest thinker!

Answer (score 2):

You are a

> EMT or Emergency Medical Service person

With jolt or breath, I dine with death

> With either a defibrillator or 'the breath of life' aka CPR, you save lives. Dining with death refers to the closeness to death that EMT's experience in their line of work

Unwanted by most, light I can boast

> No one wants to see the EMT because it means they're hurt and the light is a reference to the idea that people see 'the light' when dying.

Lecturn or wall, tethered, not all

> Not sure yet

Your will or my squall, the point of my call

> If you die, you leave a will, and the ambulance doesn't use sirens when picking up a deceased person. If you are not dead, the ambulance comes sirens blazing to your aid. They only come to your aid, however, if 911 is called (or whatever equivalent of 911 it is outside of the U.S., I'm not sure)

Comment: No sir, keep trying (I'm flattered that it's not too easy!)

Comment: Great thinking on the clues though!

Comment: Dang! I was certain (besides the fact that I didn't understand the third line) that I had it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking

> Fire

*With jolt or breath, I dine with death*

> Lightning strike or 'breath' (possible fanning motion to feed oxygen)

*Unwanted by most, light I can boast*

> Wildfire, esp. currently in the western region

*Lecturn or wall, tethered, not all*

> Unable to be contained

*Your will or my squall, the point of my call*

> Intentionally started by man (campfire), or wildfire

Comment: Great thoughts, but that is incorrect. Keep trying!